# String not in a list of case-insensitive strings (Mongodb query)

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, mongodb, pymongo

How do i find a string which is not in a list of strings ? This has to be case insensitive. Similar to a regex query, but its a list. Iam trying to use this approach in pymongo, but it is not working.

```
 exclude_file_name_substr = ["system","screenshot"]
 regex_str_list = [".*"+re.compile(substr)+".*/i" for substr in exclude_file_name_substr]
```

But iam facing this error upon running it.

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "re.Pattern") to str
```

Here, my db query has to be such as :

```
query = {}
if regex_str_list:
    query["file_name"] = {"$nin":regex_str_list}
```

So if my file_name is "System_info.png" , i should exclude this entry in the result.

Any way i could correct this ??

Answer (score 0):

So the error is caused because you are trying to concatenate a string and a regex. re.compile creates a regex Pattern object, which doesn't concatenate with strings. You should instead be doing re.compile on the concatenated string. Additionally, you should use the flag option in re.compile to specify the case insensitive flag.

```
import re
exclude_file_name_substr = ["system","screenshot"]
regex_str_list = [re.compile(".*" + substr + ".*", re.IGNORECASE) for substr in exclude_file_name_substr]

# for demonstrating the regex list on the test case
for regex in regex_str_list:
    match = regex.match("System_info.png")
    if match:
        print(match)
```

generates: `<re.Match object; span=(0, 15), match='System_info.png'>`. I'm not as familiar with the db query syntax though, but the regex itself should work.

Another thing to note is that pattern.match will match substrings, so if we replace the regex list with this

```
regex_str_list = [re.compile(substr, re.IGNORECASE) for substr in exclude_file_name_substr]
```

it will instead generate `<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='System'>` since the regex does not include line start and end. Whether or not this will work with your query I am again unsure.